# Better to write <?php or <?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

So I noticed that you can write PHP programs either like

```
<?php
// do something
?>
```

or

```
<?
// do something
?>
```

What's the difference and what's the best practice?

Comment: see here:
http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: Sorry I didn't know it was called "short tags".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use

```
<?php
```

because in some hosts the short tags are not allowed. This avoids some headaches.

There's no difference at all. Except

```
<?= $var ?>
```

that acts like an "echo"

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<?php` whenever possible, with `short_open_tag=off` (see php.ini) `<?` just won't work and code will be treated as html.